# Possible tag synonyms

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

I think that the following tags might be synonyms:

- [competitive-game](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/competitive-game) and [strategy](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/strategy) (where strategy is the better choice)
- [path-finding](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/path-finding) and [reachability](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reachability) (with reachability as better choice). Also [solvability](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/solvability) seems to cover the same concept.
- [cutting-problem](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cutting-problem) and [dissection](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dissection)
- [image](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/image) and [visual](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/visual) (with visual as better choice)
- [cryptic-crosswordsletter](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cryptic-crosswordsletter) (occurring only once) and [cryptic-crosswords](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cryptic-crosswords)
- [treasure-hunt](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/treasure-hunt) and [puzzlehunt](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/puzzlehunt) (with puzzlehunt or puzzle-hunt the better choice)
- [network](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/network) and [graph-theory](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graph-theory) (where graph-theory is the better choice)

Answer (score 5):

Looks like all of these have been dealt with by now, **except** :

- [network](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/network)      and
  [graph-theory](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graph-theory) (where graph-theory is the better choice)

Indeed,
[network](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/network) (11 puzzles
               and its description even mentions graph theory)
should become a synonym for
[graph-theory](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graph-theory) (58 puzzles).